# Why is XML called a "language" exactly?

Tags: language-design, xml, languages, markup

I've been wondering why XML has an L in its name.

By itself, XML doesn't "do" anything. It's just a data storage format, not a language! Languages "do" things.

The way you get XML to "do" stuff, to turn it into a language proper, is to add `xmlns` attributes to its root element. Only then does it tell its environment what it's about.
One example is XHTML. It's active, it has links, hypertext, styles etc, all triggered by the `xmlns`. Without that, an XHTML file is just a bunch of data in markup nodes.

So why then is XML called a language? It doesn't describe anything, it doesn't interpret, it just is.

Edit: Maybe my question should have been broader. Since the answer is currently "because XML was named after SGML, which was named after GML, etc" the question should have been, why are markup languages (like XML) called languages?

Oh, and WRT the close votes: no, I'm not asking about the X. I'm asking about the L!

Comment: On what do you base your requirement that a language has to "do" something? I don't see that in any of the definitions at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/language?s=t).

Comment: @kdgregory Those are human languages, not computer languages. However, but anyway the page makes a big deal of the "communication" part. A language is meant to be understood by both parties, the sender and the receiver. This is what xml does _only_ if it contains namespace information!

Comment: Just like Swahili is only understood if both understand it. Or a medical journal article is understood if the reader understands that part of the language. It's no different. And people make up the definitions.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88405/why-is-xml-not-called-eml?rq=1 contains the answer:  because the people who named it had a vote on various names and XML won.

Comment: Markup language is a common term  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language

Comment: @MrLister: _"Those are human languages, not computer languages"_ A language is a language. At its most extreme, even English requires contextual information (which dialect is being used) to understand unambiguously. Doesn't stop it from being a language. Your question simply has a false premise.

Comment: [On another note...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/28098/why-does-it-matter-that-html-and-css-are-not-programming-languages)

Comment: Because the L in "XML" stands for "language".  (And XML **does** describe something -- it describes the "markup".)

Comment: @DanielRHicks Ehm, you are answering my question about _why XML has an L in its name_ with _because the L stands for "language"_?

Comment: Note that nothing would prevent from inventing an XML interpreter that takes any well-formed XML document and executes it. You'd have to define the semantics of the XML markup in terms of operations, so you'd end up with a programming language that is completely unreadable, but it could be done. And you can do the opposite: think of programs as simply describing data. See denotational semantics for example. With that you could take a Java program and see it as a description of a mathematical (continuous) function between certain semantic domains.

Comment: @Bakuriu You're describing XSLT there. Semantics, check. Completely unreadable, check.

Comment: Languages don'rt *do* things, they *express* and *communicate* things

Comment: If the only reason to call it a "language" was to annoy the pedants, I think that would be reason enough.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt OK, but please note that a) the tags to my post saying "programming" were not added by me, and b) most of us are also pedants!

Comment: `It doesn't describe anything, it doesn't interpret, it just is.` So? Doesn't mean it isn't a language. This is a silly question.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ That may well be, but it was something I was wondering about, and asking in here got me not just the answer, but much other food for though as well, so I'm glad I did.

Comment: The definition of a formal language is a set of finite strings (from some alhphabet). The set of all possible XML documents is a language.

Comment: Languages can express *what to do*.  Note that *what to do* is a recipe to create almost anything, provided someone understands the language.

Comment: Lots of languages don't "do" anything. Query languages describe a model of desired information and constraints required to retrieve it -- but it's up to the query engine to decide how to use them. Markup languages alter content to add context, content handling advice or categorization -- which makes that content easier for an engine to digest. One could even argue most high level programming languages don't "do" anything outside the context of a compiler or interpreter -- Java won't run on V8, for example.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Programming Language vs Markup Language vs Scripting Language](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/241104/programming-language-vs-markup-language-vs-scripting-language)

Comment: In a computer science context, "language" means a sequence of symbols, following a set of rules.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5175840/327083

Comment: I think you are getting the concept of a language mixed up with a **Turing complete language**, which are a subset of languages - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness

Comment: @Vatine To refine that more, computer science defines a language as a subset of all possible strings over a set of symbols. Viewed another way, the only basic requirement of a language is to be able to tell which strings are inside the language and which strings are outside. The definition does not require the language to have meanings, actions, or rules.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

The real answer is XML has an L in the name because a guy named Raymond **L**orie was among the designers of the first "markup language" at IBM in the 1970'ies. The developers had to find a name for the language so they chose **GML** because it was the initials of the three developers (Goldfarb, Mosher and Lorie). They then created the [backronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) *Generalized Markup Language*.

This later became standardized as SGML (*Standardized General Markup Language*), and when XML was created, the developers wanted to retain the ML-postfix to indicate the family relationship to SGML, and they added the X in front because they thought it looked cool. (Even though it doesn't actually make sense - XML is a meta language which allows you to define extensible languages, but XML is not really extensible itself.)

As for your second question if XML can legitimately be called a language:

Any structured textual (or even binary) format which can be processed computationally can be called a language. A language doesn't "do" anything as such, but some software might process input in the language and "do" something based on it.

You note that XML is a "storage format" which is true, but a textual storage format can be called a language, these term are not mutually exclusive.

Programming languages are a subset of languages. E.g. HTML and CSS are *languages* but not *programming languages*, while JavaScript is a real programming language. That said, there is no formal definition of *programming language* either, and there is a large grey zone of languages which could be called either data formats or programming languages depending on your point of view.

Given this, XML is clearly a language. just not a *programming language* - though it can be used to define programming languages like XSLT.

Your point about namespaces is irrelevant. Namespaces are an optional feature of XML and do not change the semantics of an XML vocabulary. It is just needed to disambiguate element names if the format may contain multiple vocabularies.

---

Edit: reinierpost pointed out that you might have meant something different with the question than what I understood. Maybe you meant that specific vocabularies like XHTML, RSS, XSLT etc. are languages because they associate elements and attributes with particular semantics, but the XML standard itself does not define any semantics for specific elements and attributes, so it does not feel like a "real language".

My answer to this would be that XML *does* define both syntax and semantics, it just defines it at a different level. For example it defines the syntax of elements and attributes and rules about how to process them. XML is a "metalanguage" which is still a kind of language (just like metadata is still data!). As an example [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) is also clearly a language, but its purpose is to define the syntax of other languages, so it is also a metalanguage.

Comment: There is a [formal definition of a language in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language).

Comment: @Snowman: A "formal language" does not necessarily correspond to what is usually called a language in computing. For example a "formal language" does not need to be textual - machine code is as a formal language as is most binary formats and protocols. So I wouldn't say the term "formal language" covers the same meaning as "language" in computing.

Comment: I am not aware of any requirement that a language needs to be textual or not be textual. The idea of constructing a sentence from terminals has nothing to do with an arbitrary interpretation of the bits in those terminals, or which types of computers (silicon or carbon-based) are capable of reading them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Good point, machine code is definitely a language. I just think it is more common to call binary languages "formats", e.g. you say the GIF-format not the GIF-language.

Comment: Let's keep it at this.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, just as XML represents a tree structure, all programming languages (including machine code) are also tree-like in structure.   Terms such as "language" and "format" seem to be more colloquial rather than strictly technical.

Comment: @BenCottrell: How is machine code tree-like in structure?

Comment: @JacquesB Sorry, to be clear I mean in terms of decision-making, each decision or `jump` could be represented as a path in a 'tree'

Comment: @BenCottrell: Wouldn't it be a graph then, since is may have loops?

Comment: Fun fact: XML can in fact be used as a programming language: See e.g. [o:XML](http://www.o-xml.org/), which is an object-oriented programming language based on XML. You have just gazed into the abyss, and it gazed back into you.

Comment: Minor nitpick - "...in 1969, together with Ed Mosher and Ray Lorie, I invented Generalized Markup Language (GML) " according to Goldfarb (source: http://www.sgmlsource.com/history/roots.htm)

Comment: @Ben Cottrell '"all programming languages" are tree-like' - only at the context free level of analysis, what we usually call parsing. Once you tie symbol usages to definitions, which is essential for interpreting or compiling, they become graph structures. As for machine code - you can force it into a tree, but it's a pretty degenerate tree. Machine code, unlike higher level languages, isn't built around recursively nesting expressions.

Comment: Anybody ever used [struts logic tags](http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.1/documentation/ja/target/userGuide/printer/struts-logic.html), that proves that XML can be a programming language and it also proves that it's a really bad idea to do logic with XML.

Comment: why does everyone who uses the word "backronym" link to the definition of the word...

Comment: The definition of a language in formal language theory is very narrow and crafted for a particular purpose - it does *not* cover how the term is typically used in IT or in computer science - only one aspect of it. In IT, languages usually have both a form (syntax) and meaning (semantics). The questioner seems to argue that XML doesn't have a semantics, only a syntax.

Comment: @reinierpost: Good point, I read the question differently, but your interpretation makes sense. I have added a bit to the answer.

Comment: I think it's a great answer!

Comment: The use of "storage format" is interesting.  I think that is how a lot of written language came about.  Everything was word of mouth, then people made notes of numbers.  Then they made labels to remind them what the numbers were counting.  Then I guess someone worked out that if "three baskets of corn" could be done as symbols it would not be hard to make a symbol for "give me" or similar.

Answer (score 180):

Because it is a language. A *markup* language, not a programming language.

Notice that natural human languages like English and Spanish don't "do" anything either. In fact, technically C++ and Java and the like don't "do" anything until they're fed into a compiler and the output gets executed. Doing stuff and being a language are largely orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Substitute "interpreter" for "compiler". Being fed to a compiler doesn't make them "do" anything, either, it just translates them into a different language, which, again, doesn't "do" anything. All execution is interpretation. Sometimes, the interpreter might be extremely simple and implemented in silicon, in which case we call it an "execution unit", but it's still an interpreter. `</nitpick>` Anyway, good answer!

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good point. Since I randomly chose languages that are normally compiled, added "and the output gets executed".

Comment: An *extensible* markup language, if you will.

Comment: Also if a DSL uses XML as a transport then it can become a programming language as well. It's eXtensible that way.

Comment: I'd argue that human languages do "do" things. See Speech-Act Theory...

Comment: Sweet, sweet orthogonality.  Execute the language in a different algebra, and a whole new set of actions unfolds.  Under theory, anyway.

Comment: @Ray I'd refute that on the grounds that mimes can do all these things without the use of language. That and it's the person doing the thing, not the language.

Comment: @Pharap Not that I agree with Ray, but mimes do use language. It just isn't spoken language. Of course, this still goes against what Ray suggests (as do facts like the existence of humans who were deaf all their life). Does the language you use affect the way you act and think? Maybe, IIRC that's still a "hot" debate in some circles. But overall, people affect language more than language affects people - if I find there isn't a good word for something I want to express, I just make a new word. It happens all the time.

Comment: @Luaan Arguably body language doesn't count as a natural language because there's no fixed system. Unless mimes are communicating with some sort of sign language.

Comment: @Pharap It's a lot more flexible than "spoken language", sure. But ultimately, the goal is to enable communication between two people. And it does that, even though it's imperfect (What language is perfect, though? Even Lojban allows for ambiguities, although it makes them more obvious). If you see a mime miming climbing a rope, and you understand it to mean "climbing a rope"... why wouldn't that be a language?

Comment: @Ray: A language will not "do" anything if there is no one listening/observing.

Comment: William Shatner does things with human language.

Answer (score 103):

Let Σ be a non-empty, finite set of symbols, called an [**alphabet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_%28formal_languages%29). Then Σ* is the countable infinite set of finite words that can be formed by concatenating zero or more symbols from Σ. Any well-defined subset *L* ⊆ Σ* is a [**language**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language).

Let's apply this to XML. Its alphabet is the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character set *U*, which is non-empty and finite. Not every concatenation of zero or more Unicode characters is a well-formed XML document, for example, the string

```
<tag> soup &; not <//good>
```

is clearly not. The subset XML ⊂ *U** that forms [**well-formed** XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) documents is [**decidable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set) (or “recursive”). There exists a machine (algorithm or computer program) that takes as input any word *w* ∈ *U** and after a finite amount of time, outputs either 1 if *w* ∈ XML and 0 otherwise. Such an algorithm is a sub-routine of any XML processing software. Not all languages are decidable. For example, the set of valid C programs that terminate in a finite amount of time, is not (this is known as the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). When one designs a new language, an important decision to make is whether it should be as powerful as possible or whether the expressiveness would better be restricted in favor of decidability.

Some languages can be defined by means of a [**grammar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) that is said to *produce* the language. A grammar consists of

- a finite set of *literals* (also called *terminal symbols*),
- a disjoint finite set of *variables* of the grammar (also called *non-terminal* symbols),
- a distinguished *starting symbol*, taken from the set of variables and
- a finite set of rules (so-called *productions*) that allow certain kinds of replacements.

Any word that consists exclusively of literals and can be derived by starting with the starting symbol and then applying the given rules belongs to the language produced by the grammar.

> For example, the following grammar (in rather informal notation) lets you derive exactly the integers in decimal notation.
>
> 1. The literals of the grammar are the digits `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, and `0`.
> 2. The variables are the symbols *S* and *D*.
> 3. *S* is the starting symbol.
> 4. Any occurrence of the variable *S* may be replaced
>
>    - with the literal `0` or
>    - by any of the literals other than `0` followed by the variable *D*.
> 5. Any occurrence of the variable *D* may be replaced
>
>    - by any of the literals followed by another instance of the variable *D* or
>    - by the empty string.
>
> Here is how we derive `42`:
>
> *S* —(apply rule 4, 2<sup>nd</sup> variant)→ `4` *D* —(apply rule 5, 1<sup>st</sup> variant)→ `42` *D* —(apply rule 5, 2<sup>nd</sup> variant)→ `42`.

Depending on how elaborate rules you allow in your grammar, differently sophisticated machines are required to prove that a given word can actually be produced by the grammar. The example given above is a *regular* grammar, which is the most simple and least powerful. The next powerful class of grammars are called *context-free*. These grammars are also very simple to verify. XML (unless I'm overlooking some obscure feature I'm not aware of) can be described by a context-free grammar. The classification of grammars forms the [**Chomsky Hierarchy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) of grammars (and therefore languages). Every language that can be described by a grammar is at least [**semi-decidable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) (or “recursively enumerable”). That is, there exists a machine that, given a word that actually belongs to the language, derives a proof that it can be produced by the grammar within finite time, and will never output a wrong proof. Such a machine is called a *verifier*. Note that the machine may never halt when given a word that doesn't actually belong to the language. Clearly, we want our programming languages be described by less powerful grammars for the benefit of being able to reject invalid programs within finite time.

**Schemata** are an addition to XML that allow refining the set of well-formed documents. A well-formed document that follows a certain schema is called **valid** according to that schema. For example, the string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>all evil</root>
```

is a well-formed XML document but not a valid XHTML document. There exists schemata for [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) and what not else. Schema validation can also be done by an algorithm that is guaranteed to halt after finite amount of steps for every input. Such a program is called a [**validator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_validation) or a validating parser. Schemata are defined by so-called *scema definition languages*, which are a way to formally define grammars. [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) is the official schema-definition language for XML and is, itself, XML-based. [RELAX NG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG) is a more elegant, much simpler and slightly less powerful alternative to XSD.

Because you can define your own schemata, XML is called an **extensible** language, which is the origin of the “X” in “XML”.

You can define a set of rules that gives XML documents an interpretation as descriptions of computer programs. XSLT, mentioned earlier, is an example of such a programming language built with XML. More generally, you can serialize the abstract syntax tree of almost any programming language quite naturally into XML, if this is what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by well-defined subset? And why do you require that a subset of Σ* be well-defined in order for it to be a language? Wouldn't any subset be called a language?

Comment: @Giorgio: In mathematics, "well-defined" is largely just an intensifier: everything that mathematically exists is already well-defined.

Comment: @Giorgio With “well-defined” I mean that there is a formal predicate that tells whether an item belongs to the set or not. This predicate will in general not be computable but it has to be clearly specified without contradiction. Otherwise, [bad things might happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox). “The pairs of strings (*w*, *M*) where *M* is the smallest description of a Turing machine that outputs *w* and then halts” is a well-defined but non-computable (see [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)) predicate. …

Comment: … “The set containing all strings that are not contained in the set” is self-contradicting and not useful.

Comment: @5gon12eder: That set does not exist under ZFC (because the axiom schema of separation is not powerful enough to describe it); if you're using some other set theory, you should specify it.

Comment: @Kevin To which set are you referring? The Kolmogorov tuples? I'm pretty sure the language exists, though I have to admit that I've only been taught it informally and didn't work through a formal prove.

Comment: @5gon12eder: “The set containing all strings that are not contained in the set” does not exist.  The term "well-defined" is ironically not well-defined.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it was meant as an example of a silly definition of something that doesn't actually exist. Maybe a better (less obvious) one could be given.

Comment: @5gon12eder: “The set containing all strings that are not contained in the set” is not a set. Any set is, by definition, well-defined. IMO the term well-defined is redundant here.

Comment: @kevin: Exactly: any mathematical object for which there is a proper definition is well-defined, by definition. Normally, you do not say: let's consider a well-defined graph, with a well-defined node, etc. You only say well-defined if there is a chance to have an ill-defined one. So, since in the answer there is no mention of what could be an ill-defined subset of Σ*, I do not see why one should stress that the subset should be well-defined. If I speak of a set of strings, it is obvious that it should be a well-defined one.

Comment: While your answer is not wrong that is a very scary answer to pose to a layperson with no knowledge of set theory and little experience with fancy mathematical terms like 'concatenate' and 'well-defined'.

Comment: The *well-formed* property or *validation* is performed by a **grammar**. This answer had been perfect if you had mentioned that.

Comment: @ThibaultD. Good point, I've added that. It didn't exactly make the answer simpler, though.

Comment: Haha good job @5gon12eder , I did not expect you to change that much. You do things thoroughfully :)

Comment: The first paragraph made me feel I was back in theory of computation class.

Comment: @Kevin in mathematics, "well-defined", is a welcome reminder that you're still in mathematics.

Answer (score 31):

In computer science, [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) is just a set of strings, usually infinite and often described using rules (two common versions of those rules are [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [formal grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar)).

Note that this means that all a language needs is [*syntax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29), language doesn't need to describe what each valid string means (that's called [*semantics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29)).

Now, this means that programming languages are formal languages that also have semantics, which describes some computation. And for example XHTML is a formal language, whose semantics describe (roughly and informally) how a hypertext document looks and behaves.

XML is still a language, even though it doesn't have semantics itself (but many languages derived from XML do, like XHTML and XAML).

Technically, binary formats are also languages, but they're not called that way. The term "language" is reserved for human-readable formats.

Comment: Then why aren't other storage formats called languages too? The format used in BMP or JFIF files? Database files?

Comment: @MrLister Because they're not human-readable.  When they aren't human-readable we tend to call them *formats* or *data formats* instead.

Comment: @MrLister - It's worth pointing out that XML (like HTML) borrowed heavily from SGML which borrowed heavily from IBM's GML (generalized markup language) which dates to the 60's.  Having the ML demonstrates that there is some relationship between those languages.  Plus given the dates involved, the definition you use for what denotes a language in computing is something that has changed to a great extent since the use was coined.

Comment: @JamesSnell Not to be confused with the other ML language family, of course.  Yay for over-crowded acronyms!

Comment: Mason is correct, but it is important to note that formats such as BMP _do_ have languages. The difference is solely in how we refer to them.

Comment: If one is using formal tools to build a parser (or especially a validator) for JFIF etc. than the engineers may indeed refer to it as a "language". More likely though as a "grammar".

Comment: @MrLister: Well, they _are_ languages, but because they define reusable data structures they have a special name: _formats_. But, yes, these are languages too.

Comment: @svick But there are lots of human-readable data formats that aren't called languages. RTF springs to mind. Why wouldn't that be called RTL then? Still not sure I like any of the answers enough to accept one.

Comment: @MrLister: Naming a format is more a question of marketing. The XML people called XML for XML because "*ML" indicates a family relationship to predecessor format like GML and SGML, and because they thought it looked cool with an X in the front. And GML was called GML because it was a generalized markup language, but also because it was the initials of the three language designers. So basically the L in XML is because a guy called Raymond **L**orie was among the designers of the first markup language.

Comment: @JacquesB That's the best answer so far, but I'm afraid this means the question is asking for opinions. It was just a design decision based on some arbitrary criteria! Oh well.

Comment: @MrLister: It is not really an opinion question since it is known why the developers chose the name. It would be an opinion question if you asked if it is a good name.

Comment: @MrLister But all those formats are *also* languages. I'm not sure if the two are orthogonal or inclusive, but they definitely aren't exclusive. BMP is a language used to describe a two-dimensional set of picture elements. JFIF is a language used to describe a two-dimensional set of picture elements - note that there's many different JFIFs and specific algorithms, but only one language. Is XML a format? Maybe. But it's definitely a language, especially in the full self-descriptive form. Anyway, XMF was already used for music files, so... :D

Comment: I had to dig far too damn deep to read the right answer, containing the word **grammar**.

Comment: @ThibaultD. same here, except that I could have been content with *syntax* and *semantics*.

Answer (score 12):

A language is a method of conveying information.

A programming language is a method of conveying algorithms.

A markup language like XML is a language for conveying data.

Comment: ... and that data may very well be a description of an algorithm.

Comment: @Luaan ...and a programming language can also be abused to convey data. Like with JSON, for example.

Comment: You can even recurse. I've seen NAnt scripts (an XML-based language) that contained C# code, which was only used for data storage. Using string literals that contained XML. Yes, it's the kind of thing that makes grown men cry :P

Answer (score 2):

XML is a meta-language.  You use it to define specific languages.  Languages never do anything, they just allow us to express things.
Also, it is not true that XML is a "storage language".  Just the opposite, in fact.  You can store XML docs however you please.  XML is better thought of as a transfer language.
PS.  If you don't think XML "does" anything, you'll have to explain how it is that many systems (e.g. jetty) use XML as a (bad) programming language.   It's a lamentable abuse of XML, but it exists in the wild, and that just one of many examples.